# Differences in Ubuntu packaging? Eclipse vs. Firefox

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, packaging, eclipse

Installing a reasonably recent version of Eclipse on Ubuntu (as its [upstream Debian](https://packages.debian.org/stable/eclipse)) requires a manual install (downloaded directly from the Eclipse website, or a PPA if one can be found). Compare the [latest version on the Eclipse site](https://eclipse.org/downloads/) with the [version available in the Ubuntu packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=eclipse) and you see what I mean.

Numerous questions on Askubuntu (e.g. see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/272283/181442)) and elsewhere on the web (also on [this very site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/58824/55900)) are related to the problems that come with this practice.

I am familiar with [the general reasons why the official package repositories are often outdated](https://askubuntu.com/a/151304/181442), but then again we have other software (such as Firefox) to which these rules don't seem to apply -- just compare the [latest version released by Mozilla](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/notes/) with the [version found in the Ubuntu packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=firefox).

Now my question: Is it just that the package maintainers put more effort in keeping Firefox up-to date rather than Eclipse or is there a more fundamental (maybe technical) difference in how these programs are packaged?

Comment: This seems to be a question about what is going on in the package maintainers heads. Have you tried asking them? Or read the Debian policies.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor My question is whether there are any packaging differences between these packages or there is another reason. If you know anything that may help shed a light on this, feel free to comment or answer.