# Can't add program to favorites in Debian Jessie

Tags: gnome, kde, icons

I've just installed KDE's KolourPaint in my Debian 8 (though I'm using Gnome, it's working very well -- and it's the most similar to Windows' Paint I've found up to now).

The problem is: like some other programs (Soulseek and RStudio), I don't have the option "Add to favorites" to keep the icon in the side bar (Activities). Why isn't that option there?

I have found the launcher located in:

```
/usr/share/applications/kde4
```

, then copied it to my Home folder (like I did with the other programs), but that's not the best option, I think.

I've read [somewhere else](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/59654/134202) that the launcher must be named exactly like the program in `/usr/bin`, but it didn't solve it for me.

Anyone can point me to the proper solution? Or at least explain what's going on?

EDIT: contents of /usr/share/applications/kde4/kolourpaint.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]

Name=KolourPaint
Name[ar]=كُولُرْبينْت
Name[ast]=KolourPaint
Name[be]=KolourPaint
Name[bg]=KolourPaint
Name[br]=KolourPaint
Name[bs]=KolurPaint
Name[ca]=KolourPaint
Name[ca@valencia]=KolourPaint
Name[cs]=KolourPaint
Name[cy]=KolourPaint
Name[da]=KolourPaint
Name[de]=KolourPaint
Name[el]=KolourPaint
Name[en_GB]=KolourPaint
Name[eo]=KolourPaint
Name[es]=KolourPaint
Name[et]=KolourPaint
Name[eu]=KolourPaint
Name[fa]=KolourPaint
Name[fi]=KolourPaint
Name[fr]=KolourPaint
Name[ga]=KolourPaint
Name[gl]=KolourPaint
Name[he]=KolourPaint
Name[hi]=के-कलर-पेंट
Name[hne]=के-कलर-पेंट
Name[hr]=KolourPaint
Name[hu]=KolourPaint
Name[ia]=KolourPaint
Name[is]=KolourPaint
Name[it]=KolourPaint
Name[ja]=KolourPaint
Name[kk]=KolourPaint
Name[km]=KolourPaint
Name[ko]=KolourPaint
Name[ku]=KolourPaint
Name[lt]=KolourPaint
Name[lv]=KolourPaint
Name[mr]=कलरपेंट
Name[ms]=KolourPaint
Name[nb]=KolourPaint
Name[nds]=KolourPaint
Name[ne]=रङ पेन्ट
Name[nl]=KolourPaint
Name[nn]=KolourPaint
Name[pa]=ਕੇ-ਰੰਗ-ਪੇਂਟ
Name[pl]=KolourPaint
Name[pt]=KolourPaint
Name[pt_BR]=KolourPaint
Name[ro]=KolourPaint
Name[ru]=KolourPaint
Name[se]=KolourPaint
Name[si]=KolourPaint
Name[sk]=KolourPaint
Name[sl]=KolourPaint
Name[sr]=Колор-сликање
Name[sr@ijekavian]=Колор-сликање
Name[sr@ijekavianlatin]=Kolor-slikanje
Name[sr@latin]=Kolor-slikanje
Name[sv]=Kolourpaint
Name[ta]=நிற பெயின்ட் 
Name[tg]=KolourPaint
Name[th]=วาดภาพระบายสี-K
Name[tr]=KolourPaint
Name[ug]=KolourPaint
Name[uk]=KolourPaint
Name[uz]=KolourPaint
Name[uz@cyrillic]=KolourPaint
Name[vi]=KolourPaint
Name[x-test]=xxKolourPaintxx
Name[zh_CN]=KolourPaint
Name[zh_HK]=KolourPaint
Name[zh_TW]=KolourPaint 小畫家
GenericName=Paint Program
GenericName[af]=Verf Program
GenericName[ar]=برنامج التلوين
GenericName[ast]=Programa de pintura
GenericName[bg]=Графичен редактор
GenericName[br]=Goulev tresañ
GenericName[bs]=Program za slikanje
GenericName[ca]=Programa de pintura
GenericName[ca@valencia]=Programa de pintura
GenericName[cs]=Program pro malování
GenericName[cy]=Rhaglen Peintio
GenericName[da]=Maleprogram
GenericName[de]=Mal- und Zeichenprogramm
GenericName[el]=Πρόγραμμα ζωγραφικής
GenericName[en_GB]=Paint Program
GenericName[eo]=Pentrilo
GenericName[es]=Programa de pintura
GenericName[et]=Joonistusprogramm
GenericName[eu]=Marrazteko programa
GenericName[fa]=برنامه رنگ
GenericName[fi]=Piirto-ohjelma
GenericName[fr]=Programme de dessin
GenericName[ga]=Clár Péinteála
GenericName[gl]=Programa de debuxo
GenericName[he]=תוכנית ציור
GenericName[hi]=पेंट प्रोग्राम
GenericName[hne]=पेंट प्रोग्राम
GenericName[hr]=Program za slikanje
GenericName[hu]=Rajzolóprogram
GenericName[ia]=Programma per pinger
GenericName[is]=Teikniforrit
GenericName[it]=Programma di disegno
GenericName[ja]=ペイントプログラム
GenericName[kk]=Сурет салу бағдарламасы
GenericName[km]=កម្មវិធី​គូរ
GenericName[ko]=그리기 프로그램
GenericName[ku]=Bernameya Nexşe Kirinê
GenericName[lt]=Piešimo programa
GenericName[lv]=Krāsošanas programma
GenericName[mr]=रंग कार्यक्रम
GenericName[ms]=Program Mewarna
GenericName[nb]=Tegneprogram
GenericName[nds]=Maalprogramm
GenericName[ne]=रङ्गयाउने कार्यक्रम
GenericName[nl]=Tekenprogramma
GenericName[nn]=Måleprogram
GenericName[pa]=ਰੰਗ ਪਰੋਗਰਾਮ
GenericName[pl]=Program Paint
GenericName[pt]=Programa de Pintura
GenericName[pt_BR]=Programa de desenho
GenericName[ro]=Program de desenare
GenericName[ru]=Простой редактор изображений
GenericName[se]=Málenprográmma
GenericName[si]=පින්තාරු වැඩසටහන
GenericName[sk]=Kresliaci program
GenericName[sl]=Program za risanje
GenericName[sr]=Програм за сликање
GenericName[sr@ijekavian]=Програм за сликање
GenericName[sr@ijekavianlatin]=Program za slikanje
GenericName[sr@latin]=Program za slikanje
GenericName[sv]=Ritprogram
GenericName[ta]=பெயிண்ட் நிரலி
GenericName[tg]=Муҳаррири графикӣ
GenericName[th]=โปรแกรมวาดภาพ
GenericName[tr]=Boyama Uygulaması
GenericName[ug]=سىزىش پروگراممىسى
GenericName[uk]=Програма для малювання
GenericName[uz]=Chizish dasturi
GenericName[uz@cyrillic]=Чизиш дастури
GenericName[vi]=Chương trình vẽ
GenericName[wa]=Program di dessinaedje
GenericName[xh]=Udweliso lwenkqubo lwepeyinti
GenericName[x-test]=xxPaint Programxx
GenericName[zh_CN]=绘图程序
GenericName[zh_HK]=繪圖程式
GenericName[zh_TW]=繪圖程式
Icon=kolourpaint

Type=Application
Exec=kolourpaint %u
X-DocPath=kolourpaint/index.html

# SYNC: Run branches/kolourpaint/control/scripts/kde4port/gen_mimetype_line.sh in
#       the version of kdelibs/kimgio/ (e.g. KDE 4.0) KolourPaint is
#       shipped with.
MimeType=image/bmp;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/jp2;image/jpeg2000;image/png;image/tiff;image/x-dds;image/x-eps;image/x-exr;image/x-hdr;image/x-ico;image/vnd.microsoft.icon;image/x-pcx;image/x-portable-bitmap;image/x-portable-graymap;image/x-portable-pixmap;image/x-psd;image/x-rgb;image/x-tga;image/x-xbitmap;image/x-xcf;image/x-xpixmap;video/x-mng;image/x-sun-raster;image/svg+xml;image/svg+xml-compressed;image/x-webp;

Categories=Qt;KDE;Graphics;2DGraphics;RasterGraphics;
Terminal=false
```

Google-Earth also don't have an "Add to Favorites" option (and show no icon either, during an Alt+Tab or in the Launcher panel):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Google Earth
GenericName=3D planet viewer
Comment=Explore, search and discover the planet
Exec=/opt/google/earth/free/google-earth %f
Terminal=false
MultipleArgs=false
Icon=google-earth
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Network
MimeType=application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml;application/vnd.google-earth.kmz;application/earthviewer;application/keyhole
```

Audacity shows both "Add to Favorites" and a nice, colorful icon:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Audacity
Name[de]=Audacity
Name[ru]=Audacity
GenericName=Sound Editor
GenericName[de]=Audio-Editor
GenericName[ru]=Редактор звуковых файлов
Comment=Record and edit audio files
Comment[de]=Audio-Dateien aufnehmen und bearbeiten
Comment[ru]=Запись и редактирование звуковых файлов

Icon=audacity

Type=Application
Categories=AudioVideo;Audio;AudioVideoEditing;

Exec=audacity %F
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
MimeType=application/x-audacity-project;audio/aac;audio/ac3;audio/mp4;audio/x-ms-wma;video/mpeg;audio/flac;audio/x-flac;audio/mpeg;audio/basic;audio/x-aiff;audio/x-wav;application/ogg;audio/x-vorbis+ogg;
```

**EDIT based on comments:**

GNOME version in use: 3.14.1

Comment: Do you have a '.desktop' file like the one shown in your link but for KolourPaint?  Is it located in '/usr/share/applications'?  If so, could you edit your question to include its contents?

Comment: @airhuff Yes I do, and it's located in /usr/share/applications/kde4. I'm editing it now. Thank you!

Comment: I had a go of trying to do this. As I tried, I remembered why I switched to KDE. I think gnome has acquired the same philosophy as MS-Windows “Why would you want to do that?” (make thing simple, by removing everything that we think you will not need). So everything is easy or very very  hard.

Comment: @airhuff Well, thanks for the advice. If it becomes that hard I'll try KDE as well.

Comment: What version of gnome are you using?

Comment: @Parallaxbeta Gnome 3.14.1 on Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) 64-bit.

Comment: Try chmod +x $FILENAME

Comment: and expand all the paths

Comment: @Parallaxbeta the other icons in /usr/share/applications/ don't have the +x set, but they do show the "Add to Favorites" option. So I don't think that's the point.

Comment: I have followed your steps, and it can be added to favourites on GNOME Shell 3.22.2. Try installing it from backports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [question linked by @blametheadmin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73532/cant-add-sublime-text-to-the-gnome-shell-dock) lead me to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/92470/416671), which gave me some new ideas, and googling for:

> ```
> rstudio desktop icon gnome
> ```

I found [this page](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en), which helped me create a proper desktop file.

For RStudio:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=RStudio
Comment=A GUI for R
Exec=/home/rodrigo/Downloads/RStudio/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rstudio
Icon=/home/rodrigo/Downloads/RStudio/usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/rstudio.png
Terminal=false
```

I saved this file as:

```
/usr/share/applications/rstudio.desktop
```

For KolourPaint, I noticed that I already had the `alacarte` (`main menu`) software installed. So I just clicked the KolourPaint entry there, and later unclicked. Somehow that alone solved the problem, but I saw no difference between the previous and the present `kolourpaint.desktop` (strange). But at least digging more now I know a little more about the structure of Gnome icons.

Answer (score 1):

Try `alacarte`, a program for editing GNOME menus.

Graphics -> New Item ->

- Name:

  > KolourPaint
- Command:

  ```
  /usr/share/applications/kde4/$KDE_KOLOUR_PAINT_NAME
  ```

-> OK

EDIT:

**Warning**: This version is slightly less stable, and has less support.

You may try updating to the `jessie-backports` version.

In GNOME Shell 3.22.2, I can add it to favorites.

Run the following as root:

```
echo 'deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports
```

Then you would simply update cache and proceed with the upgrade:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade -t jessie-backports gnome-shell
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to understand what's going on, not to install a new piece of software as a workaround.

Comment: @Rodrigo Could you explain what you mean by 'understand what's going on'. Do you mean that you would like to know about how the config file works, or how gnome-shell parses it?

Comment: Means I want to understand why some programs automatically show the "Add to Favorites" option, while some others don't. Whatever it takes to understand it.

Comment: Have a look at  https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/009d021e4f93bfce69d1f4497612d804c88972b6/src/shell-app.c and https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/695bfb96160033be55cfb5ac41c121998f98c328/src/shell-app-system.c

Comment: What should I be digging in those ~2k lines of code?

Comment: The functions  shell_app_system_lookup* in the second one seems to control some form of lookup. These were the only two C files in the gnome-shell git that seem to have any relevance to .desktop files and menus.

Comment: @Rodrigo have you tried the answer from(?): https://askubuntu.com/questions/73532/cant-add-sublime-text-to-the-gnome-shell-dock 
I am not running Gnome, so I couldn't test it, but..

Comment: @Rodrigo @blametheadmin `main menu` is just the full name of `alacarte`

Comment: @Parallaxbeta thanks for your help, but I didn't need to install a less stable version of Gnome Shell. See my new answer.

Comment: @Rodrigo I'm glad you managed to find a solution to this problem!

Comment: @Parallaxbeta so am I. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Parallaxbeta Although I think your answer was not what I wanted, still it was the only answer (beyond my own). So, not to waste the bounty points, I'll give them to you, because you were the one who tried the most to help me. Thank you!