# Desktop icon without image in Gnome (Debian Jessie)

Tags: debian, gnome-shell, icons, freedesktop

Following the lessons learned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/338168/134202), I tried to add an icon to [SoulSeek](http://www.slsknet.org), the file sharing network. The problem is, different from [RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/) which has a png file in one of its directories, SoulSeek runs from a single file.

However, when running from a link (created with the `Make Link` option in the context menu of the binary file), the running app has its default icon (a blue ghostly figure, visible in the launcher bar and when I press Alt+Tab).

On the other hand, the `soulseek.desktop` file I've created in `/usr/share/applications/`, though launching the app from the `Super` key (it didn't before), launches it with no icon at all.

These are the contents of `soulseek.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=SoulSeek
Comment=Free file sharing network
Exec=/home/rodrigo/Downloads/SoulseekQt-2016-1-17-64bit
Icon=/home/rodrigo/Downloads/SoulseekQt-2016-1-17-64bit
Terminal=false
```

If I remove the `Icon` key, I get the default binary icon. How to include the "blue ghost" default app icon, that seems encoded inside the binary?

Comment: @don_crissti Good option, but an universal solution (valid for other software) would be preferable.

Comment: Yeah @don_crissti. But thinking the other way around, if Debian already know how to extract the icon from the binary (after all it's shown in the Alt+Tab), why not use this knowledge to show it in the launcher too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Icon=` key should contains the path to the .png file or just the name of the file (without the `.png`) if the file is installed in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/<file size>`.

Not the path to the executable…

See: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-1.1.html

Edit: If the icons are bundled in the QT executable, you indeed will have to extract the icons before. Apparently it's possible to do so with https://github.com/gcochard/png-extractor, not tested though.

Comment: Read again: "different from RStudio which has a png file in one of its directories, SoulSeek runs from a single file"

Comment: I read it and what you are trying to do is not possible TTBOMK.

I've added the link to the xdg desktop file specification in my reply

Comment: Thanks for the interesting link. In `A. Example Desktop Entry File`, I see both `Exec` and `Icon` keys pointing to the same executable, though (unless there's a png file with the same name in the expected path).

Comment: Yes the confusion comes from that, it's quite common that the executable and the icon have the same name

Comment: So if that's actually not possible (I'll wait 7 days -- the bounty expiration time), the solution will be to somehow extract the png icon from inside the executable.

Comment: I've updated my comment with a (untested) solution to extract the icon from the executable

Comment: This looks like a javascript library. Any idea on how to use it?

Comment: It looks like a Node.JS application, so you can run it with `nodejs app.js`.