# How do you create favourite tabs in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-shell

Okay, so I am using Ubuntu 19.10 can't create a favourite for Unity3d, there is no option when I right-click on it and I am already getting sick of having to use and keep open the Terminal every time I open it. I was wondering if there was another way to get it in my favourites bar.
Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Please confirm you have changed the Desktop to Unity, for the default desktop of 19.10 is GNOME Shell.

Comment: what? I am talking about Unity3d the game development software

Comment: Unity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(user_interface)  is different than Unity3D https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(game_engine)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add eclipse to my gnome shell favorites?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58824/how-do-i-add-eclipse-to-my-gnome-shell-favorites)

Comment: not exactly, because I don't have a desktop file, it is split in two files in my downloads folder: Documentation.pkg and Unity.tar.xz, and I don't know what those those file types imply, and I don't know what binary it is.

Comment: .tar.xz is a .tar arcive inside an .xz compressed file (for .tar does not itself compress). Pkg is the standard package manager for Julia 1.0 & newer. Unlike traditional package managers, which install & manage a single global set of packages, Pkg is designed around “environments”: independent sets of packages that can be local to an individual project or shared & selected by name. Exact package sets & versions in an environment is captured in a manifest file which can be checked into a project repository and tracked in version control, significantly improving reproducibility of projects

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. But the main issue was that the discussion you linked talks about solving the issue by making sure that the file's and the file is the same as  have the same binary that's launching, but I don't know what binary it is using

Answer (score 0):

As an end-user, you can only "read" and "write" (also reset) the array that dictates the list of favourite apps by using [dconf/gsettings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193496/add-app-to-favorites-from-command-line).

Details must wait until tommorrow, there's a train waiting for me...